# How to validate repetition of characters in a string

Tags: regex, unique, repeat

I have to validate a string which can contain numbers from 1 to 7, and maximum length allowed is 7.

```
([1-7]){0,7}
```

Condition: No numbers should be repeated in the string.

eg:

```
12345  true;
11345  false  (1 is repeated) ;
98014  false  (0,8,9 are invalid);
```

Comment: In other words: Is `12341` valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done in a single regex:

```
^(?!.*(.).*\1)[1-7]{0,7}$
```

The lookahead assertion checks that all characters in the string are unique, and the actual regex only allows 0-7 digits between 1 and 7.

In Java:

```
boolean foundMatch = subjectString.matches("^(?!.*(.).*\\1)[1-7]{0,7}$");
```

Of course you can make the lookahead fail faster by replacing each `.` with `[1-7]`, but for clarity's sake I've chosen not to. (And you can drop the `^` and `$` anchors if you use the `.matches()` method since they are implicit in that case).

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd have to use two expressions. One to validate the length and digits:

```
/^[1-7]{0,7}$/
```

and one to tests whether a digit is repeated

```
/(\d).*\1/
```

`\1` is a reference to the value of the first capture group.

With the combination of both, you can validate the string. Example in JavaScript:

```
< /^[1-7]{0,7}$/.test(12345) && !/(\d).*\1/.test(12345)
> true
--
< /^[1-7]{0,7}$/.test(11345) && !/(\d).*\1/.test(11345)
> false
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reverse the check, i.e. if it matches `[^1-7]|.{8}|(.).*\1` then it's invalid.